# existence and uniqueness for $\dot x(t)=f(t,x(t))$, with $f$ measurable in $t$.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following scalar ODE

$$\dot x(t) = f(t,x(t))$$
defined on a compact interval $[0,T]$.

Assume that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous in $x$, but it is measurable in $t$. 
What can we say about the existence and uniqueness?

The standard Picard theorem assumes that $f$ is continuous in $t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is almost provided by [Carathéodory’s existence theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_existence_theorem).